# Image not displayed on JSP page

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, url-pattern

I have a simple JSP page that has one image that is part of the JSP page but that image is not displayed when I view the webpage.  I can view the webpage but it does not include the image.

I have my img folder located in several places because I am trying to fix this problem. Inside the img folder is where I have img.jpg image that should be displayed inside JSP page.

`war/img/img.jpg`

`war/WEB-INF/jsp/img/img.jpg`

I am also not able to view img.jpg directly from my web server.  For example: `//localhost:8080/register/img/img.jpg`  I get HTTP Status 404 -

Here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringExampleSanjeev</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Enable these types of content(files) to be viewed from webpage  -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is snippet of my JSP page

```
   <img border="0" src="/img/img.jpg" alt="header banner" width="304" height="228">
   <img src="<c:url value="/img/img.jpg" />" alt="TestDisplay"/>
   <img src="<c:url value='/img/img.jpg'/>" />
   <img alt="OS usage" src="/img/img.jpg">
   <img border="0" src="/WEB-INF/jsp/img/img.jpg" alt="header banner" width="304" height="228">
   <img border="0" src="/register/WEB-INF/jsp/img/img.jpg" alt="header banner" width="304" height="228">
   <img src="img.jpg">
   <img src="/img/img.jpg">
   <img src="/jsp/img/img.jpg">
   <img src="/register/jsp/img/img.jpg">
   <img src="/WEB-INF/jsp/img/img.jpg">
   <img src="/register/WEB-INF/jsp/img/img.jpg">
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Putting an simple image on JSP page should not be this hard.

Comment: which Image is not working :O all?

Comment: I can't view any image on my JSP page.  The above list is all the combination that I have tried.

Comment: Resource inside `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible. So, Images, JS, CSS etc. should go outside `WEB-INF`

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this.

images folder parallel to WEB-INF. (images folder should NOT be inside WEB-INF).

In JSP,

```
<img src="../images/img.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I am able to view my image in JSP page if I put my image folder at: serverHome/webapps/ROOT/ and I am able to access through jsp page or directly via localhost:8080/img/headerBanner.jpg.  If I put image folder at serverHome/webapps/myWebapps/img , I am not able to access my image.   I am using tomcat 7.0.21, Spring MVC 3.0 but that should not matter.  I have tried <img src="../images/img.jpg" alt=""/> and <img src="/images/img.jpg" alt=""/> and they both work fine for me. 

 Could someone explain why my images needs to be under ../ROOT/webapps folder.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by placing images in the server's directory structure as opposed to the portlet's. I'm using apache-tomcat and have it downloaded under:

C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\

In it there is a folder called "webapps" and I created a subfolder for my images there

C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\webapps\portal_content\img

From the portlet JSP (i.e. view.jsp) I refrence the image as such:

<"img src="/portal_content/img/my_image.gif">

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/img.jpg">
```

It works for me. Hope this helps.